# Xaudio sound intensity and inverse square distance

Tags: c++, audio

I've just noticed that when using Xaudio the sound intensity follows formula:

```
volume=1/distance
```

However the correct according to https://sound.pressbooks.com/chapter/intensity-and-distance-april-2019-version/ should be:

```
volume=1/(distance*distance)
```

Is there any way to change the default to correct formula?

I'm using `X3DAudioCalculate` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/x3daudio/nf-x3daudio-x3daudiocalculate

Code -
https://github.com/Esenthel/EsenthelEngine/blob/master/Engine/Source/Sound/Sound%20Buffer.cpp#L529

Example:
I've played sound at (1,0,0) position, then (2,0,0), then (4,0,0)

Listener is at (0,0,0)

Recorded system audio using GoldWave program, got following results:

[image]

X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS.pMatrixCoefficients were full=1, then 1/2, then 1/4

But shouldn't the expected values be 1, then 1/4, then 1/16?

Comment: At the moment anyone looking to help will have to look up xaudio, find out what programming language to use, write a basic program to understand the issue, write another program to demonstrate a solution and all the while search the documentation. If you can provide a minimal example, set the language tag, link to documentation you will avoid others having to do the heavy lifting. Remember, SO users are intrinsically lazy on all sides. Lowering the barrier to helping you will only be beneficial

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Got answered by user "Aressera" on https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/711052-xaudio-sound-intensity-and-inverse-square-distance/5443074/

> This is a common confusion that arises from the difference between
> sound intensity and sound pressure. Sound intensity is an energy
> quantity that does indeed fall off like 1/(r*r). However, we don't
> hear sound intensity/energy, we hear pressure, which is proportional
> to the square root of intensity. Thus, sound pressure falls off like
> 1/r. XAudio is indeed correct.